# compiled vue files served locally in a cef python browser not rendering some images

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cefpython

I've got an application that uses Cefpython to serve a local vue application however the browser is not resolving all image paths correctly. The html, js and some images are resolved to an absolute path however others are resolved to a shortened path.

The browser tries to find some images with the full correct path `D:/..../gui/vue/dist/img/image.svg` others it shortens to the incorrect path `/img/image.svg` and cannot find.

[image]

Why? How to fix this so it uses the correct path??

If I launch the application pointing cef.CreateBrowserSync function at localhost:8080 the images are all found correctly. If I point it at the index file only some images are found.

Comment: Hi, the only issue is that the browser is not resolving the image paths correctly. I will remove other bits from the queastion